# Turn Off HTML5 Number Input Spinners

Tags: html

I was trying to disable the input spinner but all I could fine here was to hide it, like this:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

But how can it be completely disabled ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/* For Firefox */
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

/* Webkit browsers like Safari and Chrome */
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Source: https://blog.rudolphk.co.za/css-tip-remove-spinner-on-input-of-number-9fc4d9cac121

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the question.

Comment: Apparently you did not even try the solution, because it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Using this Jquery you can disable it, so the mouse wheel wont change the numbers

```
$(':input[type=number]').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    $(this).blur(); 
});
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/